# How can I represent state of method execution in base class without affecting the implementation in the derived classes?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, abstract-class

I'm trying to create an abstract class, defining an abstract method, that is to be derived from other classes that implements some specific behavior in the abstract method. I want the abstract class to contain some kind of state information that represents however the implementation in the derived classes exited without errors, but I want to implement all state handling in AbstractClass and not in the deriving classes. I want to make the deriving classes totally unaware of the functionality in AbstractClass. Below is an example. I made comments in the code to describe what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(PerformWork);
            Thread t = new Thread(ts);
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            // Dependent on if ReportWork exited without expcetions
            // I want to call ReportSuccess or ReportFailure from this method.
            // However, I dont want to implement any reporting functionallity (or
            // as little as possible)
            // into the deriving classes PerformWork() method. Simply put
            // I want the deriving classes to be totally unaware of the reporting. 

        }

        public void ReportSuccess()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        }

        public void ReportFailure()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure!");
        }
        public abstract void PerformWork();
    }
```

A class deriving from AbstractClass:

```
class ConcreteImplementationClass:AbstractClass
    {
        public override void PerformWork()
        {
            // Implements some functionality
            // without knowing anything about
            // whats going on in AbstractClass.           
        }
    }
```

Do anyone have any advice for how I could achieve this functionality, or how I could create something similar?

Comment: in other words, you want to log method calls on derived classes. simple enough. AOP. see my answer.

Comment: Could you explain why you need this to be threaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you want to call `ReportSuccess()` if the `PerformWork()` is successfully and `ReportFailure()` if it fails?

Why not change

```
public abstract void PerformWork();
```

to

```
public void Start()
{
    bool result = false;

    // This will enable Perform work to operate in its own thread
    Action threadAction = new Action(() =>
        {
            result = PerformWork();
        });

    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(threadAction);
    Thread t = new Thread(ts);
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    // Dependent on if ReportWork exited without expcetions
    // I want to call ReportSuccess or ReportFailure from this method.
    // However, I dont want to implement any reporting functionallity (or
    // as little as possible)
    // into the deriving classes PerformWork() method. Simply put
    // I want the deriving classes to be totally unaware of the reporting. 

    if(result)
    {
        ReportSuccess();
    }
    else
    {
        ReportFailure();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because then PerformWork would not run on it's own separate thread.

Comment: @Clean - I modified the snippet to use an Action to have Perform work in its own thread.  You could move the ReportSucess and Failure in that thread too.  I did not because I do not know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think this is as close as I can get to my desired behavior (without getting in to AOP).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not make your base method virtual, given that you want to run code in it, then call base.PerformWork() in all the derived methods?

Comment: because that would mean the derived class must be aware of implementation details of the abstract base. Not a bad thing but the thing the OP explicitly stated as undesirable.

Comment: Yes I could, but I hoped for some really neat way of doing it without making method calls to the base class from the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing Aspect Oriented Programming, AOP.

You can easily achieve this using any number of intercept strategies. The easiest would probably be castle proxy.

See [this...](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2008/10/26/simple-aop-example-using-castle-dynamicproxy-2-0.aspx)